# TimThumb not able to load images on Rackspace

Tags: php, wordpress, timthumb

So, we are using Linux, Apache, PHP 5.4.

I'm using Wordpress 3.5, which is where our problems started.  I'm also using a theme from ThemeFuse.

I had to revert back to a really old version of TimThumb because the latest version doesnt seem to pleased with the PHP 5.4 or Wordpress 3.5.

Does anyone have any suggestion for getting v2.8.10 or v.2.8.11 to work under Wordpress 3.5 using PHP 5.4.  I have it running and working on our development site, but when i moved the website to the live domain, it broke so there is one section on my site where the images won't load.

I am just wondering if there is a known issue with either Wordpress 3.5 or PHP 5.4.

When i go to the page that uses TimThumb I see broken images on the page. Right clicking and open the image in a new window gives me further details.

The error message says that TimThumb can't find the image eventhough when i take a the url from ?src parameter and open that url up in a browser, the image loads fine.

As a temporary solution, I've reverted back to a really, really old version of timthumb.  This is not the best solution because I know this version is vulnerable. So i need to work out a final solution in the meantime.

Thanks in advance for any thoughts.

Comment: Please check 1-12 and quickly tell the outcome of this: http://www.binarymoon.co.uk/2010/11/timthumb-hints-tips/

Comment: 1. Could not find the internal image you specified. I'm using the latest version. TimThumb version : 2.8.11. I also tried versions v2.8.2 to the latest and none work.  they all do the same thing.

Comment: 3. the url passed to the timthumb.php is already url encoded.; the cache directories exist; i chmodded the folders to 777. With the older version of timthumb i saw files being saved to the cache folder, but since that script is not safe i had to delete it from my server. tried both 777 and 755 on the cache folder. i'm not making cross domain requests. Not using wordpress-mu.  I'm using JPGs. I'm not seeing any problems with any of those things to check. STUMPED.

Comment: Try this: Enable PHP error loggong to the highest setting. Log PHP errors. Provoke the error (request the image) and double cross fingers that there is some information of use in the php error log.

Comment: you do that in the timthumb script right?

Comment: Normally in php.ini. http://php.net/error_reporting http://php.net/error_log http://php.net/log_errors

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22421/discussion-between-robbiegod-and-hakre)

Comment: Conclusion: Never got TimThumb.php to work, we found a work around by adding our images to the main wordpress content block.

Comment: Oh. Was support active again or do they need longer until they come back from holiday? Just asking if we might see an answer to this question some days later probably.

Comment: George @ Themefuse has written back to me. Maybe he can see whats going on.  But its doesn't matter now since i've already removed it from my website. if he has some suggestions, I'll let you know.

Comment: Well probably it's worth to leave it here as an answer for future reference, also you might want to use it some day again, too.

Answer (score 0):

Old question but I'm going to post an answer here as I've just had issues with this. This might not answer everyone's TimThumb issues but it solved mine. I followed the [trouble shooting guide at Binary Moon](http://www.binarymoon.co.uk/2010/11/timthumb-hints-tips/) and had no joy.  Managed to find this thread here on Themeforest;

http://themeforest.net/forums/thread/tim-thumb-problem/32860

The comment by Olegnax is the key.  It's possibly a security config on the server which the hosts will have set (but the operative you deal with at the support desk might very well not know about). If you receive a 500 Internal Server Error message on images resized by TimThumb, try the following:

1. Set the file permission on timthumb.php to 700 (read, write, and execute for owner only).
2. Check the cache directory (folder) permissions. Setting it to 777 will give you a 500 – Internal Server Error. Set it to 711.

Comment: good to have your comment.  We will try this tonight as the timthumb script is still an issue.  I totally removed it from my wordpress website, but a colleague ran into the same issue.  I'll keep you posted.

Comment: My friend said he tried your solution and unfortunately it did not work for him.  I think he took the same approach I did.  He just got rid of the timthumb script from his image calls.